# Marquee Mystery

Tags: html, css

Whilst playing with marquees i've come across the following strange behaviour;

### Example A

- http://jsfiddle.net/swafe/

  ```
  <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="down" width="100%" height="200px"     behavior="alternate" style="border: none; font-size:200px;">
      <marquee behavior="alternate">
          This text will bounce
      </marquee>
  </marquee>
  ```

### Example B

- http://jsfiddle.net/5JQMk/

  ```
  <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="down" width="100%" height="300px" behavior="alternate" style="border: none; font-size:200px;">
      <marquee behavior="alternate">
          This text will bounce
      </marquee>
  </marquee>
  ```

---

### Question

Why is that in Example A the text moves in every direction whereas in Example B, all i have changed was the height of the element and the text no longer moves up and down and only moves on the x axis?

---

### DISCLAIMER

- I have no intention of ever using marquee for anything worth anything ever.

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee

Comment: I see it moving both horizontally (to the left) and vertically in both fiddles.  Note, in the second you specify a height of 300px while your CSS defines a font-size of 200px.  My browser is Firefox 21.0

Comment: @adamdunson Awesome link to an even more awesome documentation page.  I haven't used marquee since I first started fiddling with HTML.  They probably figure you can make a marquee using CSS now.

Comment: @adamdunson This question should be closed as it is off-topic, being that it is not 1999.

Comment: Good job on the edit!!

Comment: @redditor I felt i needed to clarify my sanity.

Comment: Well there's a lot of hate and anger going on in this thread, trust me, its not you, its THE BLOODY MARQUEE... BURN IT, BURN IT!

Comment: Hmmm...probably the right way to do this is to wrap the text of the marquee inside of a <blink> tag, that way as it's about to bounce the text will be hidden. If that doesn't look right, I'd probably end up going with a Java Applet that shows the text rippling on water. While you're getting it all working though, I'd recommend adding a big "UNDER CONSTRUCTION" animated gif so your users know you're working on it. Otherwise no one will sign your guestbook and join your web ring!

Comment: @aquinas you are winrar.

Comment: @aquinas Don't forget the sound for the rippling water, and a nice jackhammer to soothe the ears and remind the user that the site is under construction. Also, hide the controls so that the user feels at home, as if they're looking for the TV remote but just can't find it.

Comment: Can someone actually /please/ build the above site otherwise i will do it

Comment: @Mikey http://wonder-tonic.com/geocitiesizer/

Comment: @Charlie You forgot to add a custom cursor image :(.  My life is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* that the text will not alternate direction within the marquee if the `font-size` is around `28.7%` smaller than the height of the `marquee`.

I only tested it with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/5JQMk/5/

To reiterate, and this is still not that precise, if the `font-size` is `71.2875%` of the height of the `marquee`, it will not alternate direction, but instead move left to right.

> [ Container ] - [ Font Size ] - [ Percent of container ]
>
> 200 - 143 - 71.50%
>
> 300 - 213 - 71.00%
>
> 400 - 285 - 71.25%
>
> 500 - 357 - 71.40%
>
> Average percent = 71.2875%
>
> Rounded perfect = 71.3%

Why does this happen? I do not know. @James Montagne has an interesting idea as to why.

But the `marquee` is dumb, very dumb, so dumb that even W3C says you shouldn't use it. I'm curious to know why you were testing it so thoroughly...

Comment: It's just height of content.  If you remove extra space by using `vertical-align: top` on the inner marquee then the math makes much more sense.  This 28ish percent is just the space below the baseline since the vertical align defaults to "baseline"

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification. I guess my answer only barely makes sense under these ideal conditions. Since this question doesn't seem so significant, so I'll leave this up.

Comment: @Charlie Doesn't seem so significant!? Without the full understanding and thorough documentation of the marquee element the world will explode!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:  This appears to be a "*bug?*" in Chrome.  Works in IE as you would expect.

For whatever reason, the combination of `behavior="alternate"` and `direction="down"` only moves when the height of the content is taller than the height of the `marquee`:

Content fits exactly (no vertical movement):

http://jsfiddle.net/5JQMk/3/

Content is 1px larger:

http://jsfiddle.net/5JQMk/4/

But really... **don't use marquee**...

Comment: @James Montagne why shouldn't use marquee?

Comment: @Stiger It's a deprecated element from the caveman era of the internet. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee